# Pygame moving rectangle

Tags: python, pygame, snake

I am coding a snake game with pygame for Python 3.6 and wonder how I can make the snake move all the time, changing direction when buttons right, down, left and up pressed, like in the real snake game.

Comment: That's the core of the game; and the scope of this site does not cover providing full tutorials. We generally help you from where you are at. What have you done up to now, what have you tried, and with what are you stuck exactly?

Comment: Why did you tag this question with `javascript`?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually very simple. You don't want to zero out the velocity on frames but only change it.

```
speed = (0, 0)

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                speed = (-10, 0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                speed = (10, 0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                speed = (0,-10)
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                speed = (0, 10)

    snake.position.x += speed[0]
    snake.position.y += speed[1]
```

As you can see, the speed is changed when a button is pressed, and the speed stays constant until a new button is pressed. You can replace the `10`s with a speed variable.